# how to retrieve all "name" & "id" from json file in python3

Tags: json, python-3.x

How can i retrieve all name and id from json file.This is a short version of my json file. I want to retrieve all names and id's so that i can match them with my variable. Then i can triger some work on it.So please help me to retrieve all Id and name. I searched in google but couldn't find. Every example was of single json.

```
[
 {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1283378,
    "name": "Gorkhā",
    "country": "NP",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 84.633331,
      "lat": 28
    }
  }
]
```

Here's My Code:

```
import json

with open('city.list.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for p_id in data:
    hay = p_id.get('name')
```

suppose,i got a word delhi, now i am comparing it with name in dictionary above. when it hits i want to retrieve it's id.

```
if hay == delhi:
   ga = # retrieve delhi's id
```

Comment: Except for an indentation mistake (which I will consider a typo) of the `print` statement, I see nothing wrong with your code. Just add another `get` for the `name` field. Or did I not understand the question...?

Comment: how do you want the output, are you looking for an array of ids, names separately or any array of dict consisting of name and id? either case simple comprehension will  give answer

Comment: i want output in array of dict so that i can match a name like raj in whole dict and can get id of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for name and apply a condition:

```
    for p_id in data:
        u_id = p_id.get('id')
        u_name = p_id.get('name')
        if(u_id == 1283378 and u_name == "Gorkha"):
            # dosomthing
```

Comment: suppose i got a word delhi and i got above json containing {
    "id": 1283378,
    "name": "delhi",
    "country": "IN",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 84.633331,
      "lat": 28
    }
if (name == delhi):
   fa = # retrive its id

so i want to match delhi with dictionary and retrive its id in a var.

Comment: You can retrieve your id against city in this way:for p_id in data:
    u_name = p_id.get('name')
    if(u_name == "Gorkha"):
        print(p_id.get('id'))

Comment: I am getting id's of others. Not this aprticular one's.

Comment: `import json

with open('city.list.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    
for items in data:
    
    my1 = items.get('name')
    if my1 == "Novinki":
        print(items.get('id'))
        print("Got it")`

Comment: This is working fine for me:import json
data = [....]

for items in data:
    my1 = items.get('name')
    if my1 == "Novinki":
        print(items.get('id'))
        print("Got it") Output:519188

Comment: Thanks you so much . I have solved the issue by adding break at end and created this code.
`import json

with open('city.list.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    
for items in data:
    print(items)
    my1 = items.get('name')    
    if(my1 in 'how is the Valsad'):
      my2 = items.get('id')
      print(my2)
      print(my1)
      break`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly on your output. But this extracts id and name in a new variable.

```
ids=[]
for p_id in data:
    ids.append((p_id['id'], p_id['name']))
print(ids)
```

Output:

```
[(707860, 'Hurzuf'), (519188, 'Novinki'), (1283378, 'Gorkhā')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach, process the JSON data into a `dict` and get the information you want from that. For example:

```
import json

with open('city.list.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

name_by_id = dict([(str(p['id']), p['name']) for p in data])
id_by_name = dict([(p['name'], p['id']) for p in data])
```

And the results:

```
>>> print(id_by_name['Hurzuf'])
707860
>>> print(name_by_id['519188'])
Novinki
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

with open('citylist.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    
list1 = list ((p_id.get('id') for p_id in data if p_id.get('name') == "Novinki")) 
# you can put this in print statement,
# but since goal is to save and not just print, 
# you can store in a variable
 
print(*list1, sep="\n")
```

gives

```
519188

[Program finished]
```